# como usar el if

Tags: php

```
SELECT * from reservacion A 
            where A.FECHAOPERACION='$fechoper'AND (A.QUIROFANO='$quiro' 
AND A.CIRUJANOPRINCIPAL='$cirujano' AND A.ANESTESISTA ='$anestesista' 
AND A.INSTRUMENTISTA ='$instrumentista'
```

Comment: no se entiende la pregunta, por favor edita y explica lo que tratas de conseguir